# [R]Relenium‎ findElmentBy Innerhtml possible in R?

Tags: jquery, r, innerhtml

From what I have found this may require jQuery, if so, is there a package in R that can execute jQuery commands?

I have a page that has a list of reports with links that all have the same class, the xpath for the element I am looking for will is not static, the identifying element I am looking for is within the innerhtml. Is it possible to find this element by using the package relenium?

YRD1 is the element I need:

```
<tr class=""><td align="center"><input type="checkbox"></td><td align="left" class="undefined"><div><img onload="this.__gwtLastUnhandledEvent=&quot;load&quot;;" src="style=" 0px 0px;" border="0" class="MN NN fl" id="gwt-debug-starwidget"> <div class="wsn ml2em"> <div class="lnk">YRD1</div> <div class="gwt-Label"></div> </div></div></td><td align="left" class="undefined"><div><div><div class="lnk" style="white-space: nowrap;">YRD1 (11/18/13)</div></div> <div> <div class="lnk">All reports »</div> </div></div></td><td align="left" class="undefined">Me</td><td align="left" class="undefined"><div><div>--</div> <div class="ANB"></div></div></td><td align="left" class="undefined"><div class="gwt-Label">Nov 18, 2013</div><span class="gray">10:29 AM</span></td></tr>
```

Comment: You can use findElementByClassName or findElementByCssSelector. For example `firefox$findElementByClassName("yourclass")` or `firefox$findElementByCssSelector(".yourclass")`

Answer (score 1):

```
require(relenium)

firefox <- firefoxClass$new()
firefox$get("http://lluisramon.github.io/relenium/toyPageExample.html")

modalElement <- firefox$findElementByClassName("modal")

# or 

modalElement <- firefox$findElementByCssSelector(".modal")
```

Comment: I need to find a specific element within a group of elements that have the same class. This code will only return the first element with the class.

Comment: How would that element be identified. If you provide an example it will be easier to help you.

Comment: For this you could use an xpath such as `firefox$findElementByXPath("//*/div[@class='lnk' and contains(., 'YRD1')]")` or something similar.